# Vue.js use method of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Currently I am working with Vue CLI version ^3.0.0 and Vuex ^3.6.0, but when I want to use Vue.use(Vuex).
It says in the browser cannot read use of undefined.

Code:

main.js

```
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'

new Vue({
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'Vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        count: 0
    },
    mutations: {
        increment(state) {
            state.count++
        }
    }
})
```

[image]

Error received:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you setup vue with vue-cli you can run: `vue add vuex` and it'll do all the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Store.js`:

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({

state: {...},
mutations: {...},
action: {...},
getters: {...}

})
```

`main.js`

```js
import App from './App.vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import store from './store'

createApp(App)    
    .use(store)    
    .mount('#app')
```

Comment: And how can I use those state? Can I use it like ReactJS like this.state.name

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Vue 3, it doesn't support global config. You'll need to do it like this I think:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

const store = createStore(
  // options
);

const app = createApp(
  // options
);

app.use(store);
```

Also you will need to upgrade to `vuex@4` for Vue 3 support.

Comment: I been looking for Vuex version 4, but didnt see any version of npm install, can you maybe send a link?

Comment: Try `npm install vuex@next`

Comment: npm install vuex@4.0.0-rc.2?

Comment: I have installed your version, but now it doesn't show any result, but it doesnt give any error

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'Vuex';
```

to main.js
since you need to call before its initialize